# Convert WPF control in Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, treeview

There is an very old WPF application of Hyper Tree - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2007/10/31/mindmap-app-using-hyperbolic-tree.aspx.

The source code can be found at codeplax.com - 
http://hypertree.codeplex.com/releases/view/11524

I wanted to use this tree control in my silverlight application. Now the issue is that i am new to silverlight, and the code is using some WPF specific things.

Please suggest me to solve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Abhinav

**Update:**

things like 
`FrameworkPropertyMetadata` and `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions`, `InvalidateVisual()`, `OnRender` override, child `UIElements`.

Code Added:

```
public class SmartBorder : Decorator
{
    #region Dependency Properties
    public static readonly DependencyProperty GlowBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("GlowBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(SmartBorder), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

  ......

    #region Dependency Property backing CLR properties
......
    #endregion

    // if the button is pressed, this fires
    private static void OnRenderIsPressedChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SmartBorder border = o as SmartBorder;
        if (border != null)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue == true)
            {
                border.BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
                border.BorderWidth = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                border.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
                border.BorderWidth = 2;

            }
            border.InvalidateVisual();
        }
    }

    // if the mouse is over the control, this fires
    private static void OnRenderIsMouseOverChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SmartBorder border = o as SmartBorder;
        if (border != null)
        {
            border.InvalidateVisual();
        }

    }

    // a series of methods which all make getting the default or currently selected brush easier


    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        Rect rc = new Rect(0, 0, this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight);

        LinearGradientBrush gradientOverlay = GetGradientOverlay();
        Brush glowBrush = GetGlowBrush();
        Brush backBrush = GetBackgroundBrush();
        Brush borderBrush = GetBorderBrush();
        Pen borderPen = new Pen(borderBrush, BorderWidth);
        double cornerRadiusCache = CornerRadius;

        // draw the highlight as necessary
        if (RenderIsMouseOver)
        {
            Rect rcGlow = rc;
            double glowMove = BorderWidth * 2;
            rcGlow.Inflate(glowMove, glowMove);
            glowMove = 0;
            rcGlow.Offset(new Vector(glowMove, glowMove));
            dc.DrawRoundedRectangle(GetOuterGlowBrush(), null, rcGlow, cornerRadiusCache, cornerRadiusCache);
        }

        // we want to clip anything that might errantly draw outside of the smart border control
        dc.PushClip(new RectangleGeometry(rc, cornerRadiusCache, cornerRadiusCache));

        dc.DrawRoundedRectangle(backBrush, borderPen, rc, cornerRadiusCache, cornerRadiusCache);
        dc.DrawRoundedRectangle(gradientOverlay, borderPen, rc, cornerRadiusCache, cornerRadiusCache);

        if (!RenderIsPressed)
        {
            double clipBorderSize = BorderWidth * -4.0;
            Rect rcClip = rc;
            rcClip.Offset(clipBorderSize, clipBorderSize);
            rcClip.Inflate(-clipBorderSize, -clipBorderSize);
            dc.PushClip(new RectangleGeometry(rcClip, cornerRadiusCache, cornerRadiusCache));
            dc.DrawEllipse(glowBrush, null, new Point(this.ActualWidth / 2, this.ActualHeight * 0.10), this.ActualWidth * 0.80, this.ActualHeight * 0.40);
            dc.Pop();
        }
        // just draw the border now to make sure it overlaps everything nicely
        dc.DrawRoundedRectangle(null, borderPen, rc, cornerRadiusCache, cornerRadiusCache);

        dc.Pop();
        //base.OnRender(drawingContext);
    }


    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        UIElement child = this.Child as UIElement;

        double borderThickness = BorderWidth * 2.0;

        if (child != null)
        {

    ...
        }

        return new Size(Math.Min(borderThickness, constraint.Width), Math.Min(borderThickness, constraint.Height));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "some WPF specific things". =)

Comment: `Help you` mean explain what these things are? ... :-) ... well you have to read man... MSDN / Blogs / silverlight articles... as we may give you the concise definitions, but they will make your life harder as they will may refer some terms which you may would not know further.... BTW welcome to a challenging but wonderful world of WPF / Silverlight.... :-)

Comment: @AngelWPF thank you. But I want to know the substitutes of WPF classes in silverlight, so that I can use it.

Comment: @ago.net, again my answer does not change... refer MSDN ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903925(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` and `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions` and value coercions etc. for Silverlight see the WPF_Compatibility solution under the ClipFlair codebase (http://clipflair.codeplex.com)

Comment: you can also see references I had gathered while writing WPF_Compatibility at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/oq6x074fx1y4cev/AACF96fWv4kJvuW1eSV0Dwdxa